# Firebase functions: set region when using reserved hosting urls

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I currently have my firebase setup like this (without a config, as the reserved hosting urls load the config automatically):

```js
var functions = firebase.functions();
    if(window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
        firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
    }
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var perf = firebase.performance();
```

But, I cannot set the region to a different place, as I want it to be in `europe-west2`. I've tried adding it as a parameter to the `firebase.functions()` without success.

This is what I have tried, according to the docs:

```js
var functions = firebase.app().functions('europe-west2');
```

without success.

Is there any way that I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please file a bug report on GitHub if the documented API doesn't work the way you expect.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

For anyone looking to do the same, it is currently not supported.

You can find the relative parts in the docs for it here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client-callable_functions

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2302